# WaitForExitAsync with a timeout

Tags: c#, cmd, process

So I noticed that there's a method called `WaitForExit` that accepts and int as argument (milliseconds) so if the process isn't able to exit itself, I just killed it after some seconds.

Something like this.

```
if (!CMD.WaitForExit(3000))
    CMD.Kill();
```

The thing is that meanwhile I'd like to save the output, so I noticed that there's an async method `WaitForExitAsync` but this one doesn't accept these milliseconds.

```
// Wait for exit async...
// Meanwhile save the output till it kills itself.

while (CMD.StandardOutput.ReadLine() != null) 
    standard_output = StandardOutput.ReadLine();
```

Any idea how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: It takes a `CancellationToken`, so just pass `new CancellationTokenSource(timeout).Token`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use `CancellationTokenSource`. It has a [ctor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.cancellationtokensource.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-threading-cancellationtokensource-ctor(system-timespan)) which accepts a `TimeSpan`

```
var timeoutSignal = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
try 
{
   await CMD.WaitForExitAsync(timeoutSignal.Token);
} catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
   CMD.Kill();
}
```

When the CTS signals then the awaited operation will throw an `OperationCanceledException`. So you need to wrap your `await` call into a `try`-`catch` to handle cancelled operation properly.

---

**UPDATE #1**: Capture STDOUT with async wait of exit

#### Naive approach

First let me share with you the naive version of the code

```
Console.WriteLine("Launch ping with fifteen retries");
var terminal = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo("/sbin/ping")
{
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    Arguments = "-c 15 stackoverflow.com",
    UseShellExecute = false,
});

_ = Task.Run(() =>
{
    string line = null;
    while ((line = terminal.StandardOutput.ReadLine()) != null)
        Console.WriteLine(line);
});
            

var timeoutSignal = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
try
{
    await terminal.WaitForExitAsync(timeoutSignal.Token);
    Console.WriteLine("Ping has been Finished");
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    terminal.Kill();
    Console.WriteLine("Ping has been Terminated");
}
```

- I'm using .NET on a Macintosh machine so, I don't have `ping.exe` rather than I can run `/sbin/ping` command
- I ping stackoverflow fifteen times to make sure the command runs more than 3 seconds
- I've moved the `StandardOutput` reading to a separate thread (`Task.Run`)

  - Without that, the cancellation signal will not have any effect
- The rest of the code same as above + debug logging

#### Suggested approach

The `Process` class does expose a capability to read data asynchronously from the `StandardOutput` without the need to do extra tricks

```
Console.WriteLine("Launch ping with fifteen retries");
var terminal = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("/sbin/ping")
    {
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        Arguments = "-c 15 stackoverflow.com",
        UseShellExecute = false,
    }
};

terminal.OutputDataReceived += (s, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
terminal.Start();
terminal.BeginOutputReadLine();            

var timeoutSignal = new CancellationTokenSource(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
try
{
    await terminal.WaitForExitAsync(timeoutSignal.Token);
    Console.WriteLine("Ping has been Finished");
}
catch (OperationCanceledException)
{
    terminal.Kill();
    Console.WriteLine("Ping has been Terminated");
}
```

Let me highlight only the differences

- Rather than starting the process right away, first we create a Process and specify its `StartInfo` property
- Then we subscribe to the [`OutputDataReceived`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived?view=net-6.0) event

  - Its EventArgs' `Data` property contains the newly available information
- After the subscription we can call the `Start` method
- And finally we need to call the [`BeginOutputReadLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline?view=net-6.0) method to tell the Process fire the above event handler whenever new data is available on the standard output

Comment: `CancellationTokenSource` needs a `using`, do not dispose until the cancellation has been triggered.

Comment: Hi once again! @Peter Csala  :) sorry but I'm a little lost, since `await` keyword is awaiting for the thread to end I can't execute another code. I tried omitting the keyword await but it doesn't never stop. How could I do the while sentence and stop it after 3 seconds?

Comment: @Omar What do you want to do run in the meanwhile?

Comment: @PeterCsala I'd like to save the output of `CMD` let's say I do `ping www.google.com -t` for example, this won't stop never, so after 3 seconds it will stop due to the `WaitForExitAsync` method, nevertheless I'd like to be able to get the output generated in the meantime (for this case, every ping it did before stopped)

Comment: @Omar Ohh okay, I will update my post accordingly tomorrow.

Comment: @PeterCsala Thanks! :)

Comment: @Omar I've updated, please revisit

Comment: Thank you @PeterCsala as usual your answers are amazing. I wish I could have that programming knowledge. Also thanks for show both ways, the naive one and the way to go. Have a good day!

Comment: @Omar You will gain that level of expirience, you just need to be patient, dedicated and curious :)

Answer (score 2):

The new .NET 6 comes with `WaitAsync` method that allows asynchronously waiting for a task *with a timeout*.

```
await process.WaitForExitAsync().WaitAsync(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));

if (!process.HasExited)
{
    //timeout!
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It have a argument takes millisecond

```
WaitForExitAsync(process, timeout);
```