# Redirecting process's output isn't working C#

Tags: c#, .net, process, output-redirect

I need to send an input from a C# program to another program and capture its process's output every time after the input is sent

Here I wrote a C program to be used as a process in C# program. The program will receive an input and print back the same string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
int main(){

    while(true){
        char buff[1000];
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", buff);
        printf("\nechoed : %s\n",buff);
      }
    
}
```

This is my C# program that will send input and receive output to and from my C program
*(I am starting the process in another thread so **process.WaitForExit()** will not block the main thread)*

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;
namespace MinExample
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static StreamWriter processStreamWriter;
        static string filePath = @"my_program.exe";
        private static void MyProcOutputHandler(object sendingProcess,
            DataReceivedEventArgs outLine)
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(outLine.Data))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Data : " + outLine.Data);
            }
        }
        //this doesn't works
        static void StartProcessWithOutputRedirection()
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.FileName = filePath;
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            //standard input out redirection
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;//redirect output
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;//redirect output
            startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

            try
            {
                //Initialize process and register callback
                Process process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(MyProcOutputHandler);
                process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(MyProcOutputHandler);
                //
                process.Start();
                //initialize stream writer so that the process can receive incoming input
                processStreamWriter = process.StandardInput;

                process.BeginOutputReadLine();
                process.BeginErrorReadLine();

                process.WaitForExit();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        //this works
        static void StartProcessNoOutputRedirection()
        {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.FileName = filePath;
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            //standard input out redirection
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
           
            try
            {
                //Initialize process and set property
                Process process = new Process();
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                //
                process.Start();
                //initialize stream writer so that the process can receive incoming input
                processStreamWriter = process.StandardInput;
                process.WaitForExit();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /*
                using StartProcessNoOutputRedirection works but using StartProcessWithOutputRedirection doesn't
             */
            ThreadStart ths = new ThreadStart(StartProcessWithOutputRedirection);
            Thread th = new Thread(ths);
            th.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                Console.Write("Input :");
                string input = Console.ReadLine() ?? "";
                processStreamWriter.WriteLine(input);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It will print the output each time the process receives an output when I don't redirect the output at all

However when I tried to redirect the output, the [Process.OutputDataReceived](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) event isn't being called back. I have searched another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/285760/how-to-spawn-a-process-and-capture-its-stdout-in-net) and have tried to use **process.BeginOutputReadLine();** after **process.Start** but it hasn't solved my issue

Any advice?

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70622033/waitforexitasync-with-a-timeout/70622100#70622100 ?

Comment: The following may be helpful: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69791571/c-sharp-redirect-other-console-app-standardoutput-fail-if-i-wont-close-stardand/69792388#69792388), [Process.EnableRaisingEvents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents?view=net-6.0), and [Process.StandardInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput?view=net-6.0)