# C# Thread.Start forced to wait because of Process.WaitForExit()

Tags: c#, multithreading

This is a hard one to explain, but I'm sure something is operating as intended.

Basically, I am starting a new `Thread` like so

```
for (int i = 0; i < something.Length; i++)
{
    Thread t = new Thread(newT => new Execute(args));
    t.Start();
}
```

Inside of `Execute` I have the following,

```
Process proc = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(commandline)
};
proc.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(args);
string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string err = proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
proc.WaitForExit();
```

I'm expecting the for loop to continuously fire, so lets say I have 10 objects I just want to to fire over those 10 immediately.  However, because of the `proc.WaitForExit()` the thread waits for the exit to continue the for loop.

What can I do, to keep the for loop going?  I need each thread to wait for the exit without holding up the for loop

Comment: I've tried making this an async task as well, same behavior

Comment: The context is not clear, but perhaps you're looking for a `Semaphore` or `CountdowEvent`?

Comment: You are passing the same `args` to all `Execute` invocations. Is this intentional?

Comment: You code should work; creating 10 threads in quick succession, then each of the threads will wait for one process to exit.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70622033/waitforexitasync-with-a-timeout

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this? Threads are entirely encapsulated inside their own process. There's no need to create a new thread just to launch a new process.

Comment: Are you sure the program isn't crashing because the thread code is not complete? 1) You're not starting the process, 2) you did not redirect the output streams and thus 3) you can't use ReadToEnd on the output and error. Fixing those errors let me start N processes and then each thread waited for the process to exit, in parallel, as you describe is the goal. In short, the posted code has problems, but fixing those and it seems to work as you want.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70451991/query-user-called-via-cmd-exe-results-0-output/70452809#70452809 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents?view=net-6.0

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsensomething is going on, i'm exploring throwing more errors at this point